# PHP can't read file on /var/tmp

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I have a really strange error. PHP can't read a file that do exists... Some ideas? I have not SELinux installed. I'm using fedora 17 and php 5.4.

I already try everything I know, but the problem still remains.

```
[root@sqd var]# ls -lia 
total 92
  8194 drwxrwxrwx. 23 root   root   4096 ago 17 10:30 .
     2 dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root   root   4096 ago 13 16:00 ..
 32139 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 may 22 13:42 account
   288 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 adm
    13 drwxr-xr-x. 14 root   root   4096 ago  8 10:26 cache
796005 drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4096 feb  6  2012 cvs
   289 drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 ago 21 18:07 db
   290 drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 may 22 13:42 empty
263682 drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 ago  7 11:15 ftp
   291 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 games
 35931 drwxrwx--T.  2 root   gdm    4096 jun  8 16:05 gdm
   292 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 gopher
    15 drwxr-xr-x. 45 root   root   4096 ago 10 10:42 lib
   296 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 local
   308 lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root     11 may 22 13:39 lock -> ../run/lock
    12 drwxr-xr-x. 14 root   root   4096 ago 26 03:17 log
   297 lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root     10 may 22 13:39 mail -> spool/mail
   298 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 nis
931987 drwxrwxrwx   3 nobody nobody 4096 ago 17 10:32 nodejs
   299 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 opt
   300 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 preserve
   307 lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root      6 may 22 13:39 run -> ../run
   301 drwxr-xr-x. 15 root   root   4096 may 22 13:43 spool
   305 drwxrwxrwx.  5 nobody nobody 4096 ago 30 14:13 tmp
262637 drwxr-xr-x.  7 root   root   4096 ago  7 11:20 www
   306 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 feb  3  2012 yp


[root@sqd var]# ls -lia tmp/
total 216
    305 drwxrwxrwx.  5 nobody nobody   4096 ago 30 14:13 .
   8194 drwxrwxrwx. 23 root   root     4096 ago 17 10:30 ..
   3030 -rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nobody 199397 ago 30 14:13 file_thumb_5363_1_0.jpg
```

But

```
<?php
highlight_file(__FILE__);

var_dump(file_exists('/var/tmp/file_thumb_5363_1_0.jpg'));
```

print out:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Are you getting it when you run your php from the command line or from the browser (as a different user?)
What does `file /var/tmp/file_thumb_5363_1_0.jpg` command shows when you executed it from the shell?

Comment: @grzegorz He is logged in as root and the file perm is 777 from his ls.  Can't be a permission thing

Comment: @RobertMaysJr: I know he is logged as root - prompt sais that. Also 777 comes from -rwrxrwxrwx, and the picture shows this. I want to know if he can do `file`, and where is he getting this problem when running php from a command line (then it cannot be permission) or from a web (so it can be a permission problem.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fedora 16** introduced the concept of a "**private tmp**" `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` I would throw my 2 cents on that direction.

**[From the manual](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_Sysadmin.html):**

> 2.3.3. Services Private /tmp
>   A number of services managed by systemd have been modified to make use of its ability to provide them with a
>   private /tmp directory. Privileged services using /tmp and /var/tmp
>   have previously been found to be open to being interfered with by
>   unprivileged users, potentially leading to privilege escalation. Using
>   private /tmp directories for services prevents this style of exploit.
>
> The directive added to the systemd unit files for the modified
>   services is:
>
> [Service]
>    PrivateTmp=true

Comment: Is this all over the RHEL-based systems? My server's linux distro is **Amazon Linux** and it seems encountering the same issue.